# Excel 2007 and older version watermark workaround?

Tags: c#, .net, excel-2007, com-interop, excel-interop

I am adding an image to backgorund for Excel document to mimic a watermark by using

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

iterating through worksheet

```
foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in xlWorkBook.Worksheets)
{
//Add watermark image
sheet.SetBackgroundPicture(wswm_imgpath);
}
```

But the image will not appear when you print the document.
How can I include this background image when it is printed?
Got any idea?

Comment: Not sure what is your excel version.  Have a look in the below link https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/213977/you-cannot-print-a-background-graphic-for-a-excel-worksheet

Comment: Also check this... https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1056-excel-print-background.html